# Button to clear textarea / textboxes of content

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

would someone be able to help me with a button to clear /delete the content of all textareas on a form please?

I've already tried this approach:

```
<input type="reset" value="restart" />
```

but because the textareas are populated with data from the database upon load then it doesn't actually do anything (unless I want to re-set the form back to it's original state).

Can I do this with some code on the view? Or will I need to add some bits to the controller as well?

I'm using ASP.Net MVC Razor C# Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.

Code for the View page is below:

```
@model DFAccountancy.Models.Data

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Update";
}



<h2>Update</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"     type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { $("test").click(function () { $("textArea").val(""); }); });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Data</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.para1)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.para1, new { cols = 75, @rows = 5 })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.para1)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.para2)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.para2, new { cols = 75, @rows = 5 })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.para2)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Update" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="reset" value="Re-Start" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input id="test" type="button" />
    </p>

</fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: have you considered a javascript approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using JQuery you could assign all text areas a class and then do:

```
$(function () {
   $(".textArea").text('');
}
```

This would clear all text areas once the document has loaded.

Comment: I think jQuery also has a pseudo selector for textboxes, something like $(":text").text('');  Not sure how to combine them though.

Comment: Thanks Darren, but I need the textareas to load with the content, then should the person who is editing the data in the text areas what a quick method to clear all the data in the form they can simply click a button.

Comment: $("#btnYourButton").click(function() {
  $(".textArea").text('');
}

<input id="btnYourButton" type="button" />

Comment: Thanks again Darren, apologies, but I'm very ignorant to all this at the moment. Where does that code above go so I can test?

Comment: You should have a section in your view or an external reference for JavaScript:

Just add this to the bottom of your View:

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#btnYourButton").click(function() {         $(".textArea").text(''); }
      </script>

Comment: Thanks Darren, I've updated the code in my example above. How would I add a button to clickon that would execute the above, and therefore clear the textareas of data? (I called the #btnYourButton "test" - I guess I would have to give the button an id of "test"?

Comment: <input id="test" type="button" />

Comment: Cheers Darren, sadly not working. No error or anything, just nothing gets cleared. I've updated my code above to show the whole View page.

Comment: Jquery selectors look for Ids which are prefixed with # therefore the Jquery syntax should be $("#test).click(function() { alert('click works') });

Comment: P.s. the reason why the text boxes dont clear is because there is no element called textArea on the page and if there was it would need be be prefixed with the # as described in my comment above.

Comment: Thanks Darren, that is loads of help. Learnt a lot :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's .click event on your button:

```
 $(function () {
   $("#YourButtonID").click(function(){
      $("textArea").val("");
   });
 });
```

Comment: Thank you Duncan, apologies for the ignorance, but I am very new to all this. Should this code go into the View page?

Comment: Yes you can place it in your view page like this <script type="text/javascript"> $(function () {
   $("#YourButtonID").click(function(){
      $("textArea").val("");
   });
 });</script>, but placing it on a .js file would be better

Comment: Thanks Duncan, how would I call it from a button?

Comment: No @Harry, $("#YourButtonID").click(function(){ $("textArea").val(""); }); is already a button click listener so you just have to assign your button an ID that you want to and have it as jquery's selector. Say for example your button is <input type="button" value="Clear Fields" id="clearBTN" /> , your click listener should be $("#clearBTN").click(function(){ $("textArea").val(""); });

Comment: and notice I wrapped the .click listener inside  $(function () { [your code] }); , the wrapper means that your code will be initialized when the DOM is ready.